# JavaScript taking information from a email address

Tags: javascript, email, substring, indexof

I have been assigned a task at my university to create a web page with two text boxes and a button.

The user is to enter an email address in the format below into the first text box. The user then clicks the button and the surname will appear in the second text box. The email addresses is in the general form `forename.surname@domain.co.uk`.

My function must work for all of the following:

- first.last@domain.co.uk

I have been told to use `.substring()` and `.indexOf()` to find the
surname.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title> JavaScript </title>
        <meta name="author" content="Reece">
        <meta name="description" content="describe the website">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="myText" value=""> </br> </br> <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button> 
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script> function myFunction() { var x = document.getElementById("myText").value; document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; } </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the email address to parse. You've already done that. Here, `x` contains the email address.

```
var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
```

Now you can use `x.indexOf(".")` to get the position of the first period. Likewise, use `x.indexOf("@")` to get the position of the "@" symbol.

These two values are passed to [`x.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to get the text between the two.

Comment: thankyou i am kind of understanding it now but it still doesn't seem to be working it this i am writing it out wrong, how should pass it to the substring

Comment: @ReeceO'Sullivan - Please post what you've got now and I will happily correct whatever mistake you made. You can post a link to a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) if you like.

Comment: sorry im all new to this javascript haha, watched way to manny youtube videos.

Comment: <script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
   var n = x.indexOf(".")
   var n = x.indexOf("@")
   x.substr()
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

}
</script>

Comment: thank you that's perfect, I understand it now. was the +1 so that id didnt add the . into the answer

Comment: @ReeceO'Sullivan, yep, you got it exactly